# How can I extract ISO and ASTM standards from a text using regex?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to extract the ISO and ASTM standards from a text. The corresponding literals ISO and ASTM followed by the numbers would have to be found.

Rules:

- Match starts with ISO or ASTM
- ASTM is followed by a D
- This is followed by a number (either preceded or not with a space or hyphen) that can also contain optional spaces and hyphens
- As soon as the number sequence ends, the match ends

Possible pattern for the first two rules:

```
(?:ISO|ASTM\s*D)
```

Example:

> **ISO 527-1**, DIN EN **ISO 3349-3**, and **ASTM D143** are all testing standards. **ISO 31 33**, **ISO 334 9** are specific to static bending, but **ASTM D 149-3** includes various other 9.

https://regex101.com/r/IFlqT2/1

What would a corresponding regex look like?

Comment: The pattern matched unfortunately not "ASTM D143".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?:ISO|ASTM\s*D)(?:[\s-]*\d)+
```

*Details*:

- `(?:ISO|ASTM\s*D)` - `ISO` or `ASTM` + zero or more whitespaces + `D`
- `(?:[\s-]*\d)+` - one or more repetitions of

  - `[\s-]*` - zero or more whitespaces or hyphens
  - `\d` - a digit.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xD2eCZ/1).